# Common keyboard navigation (access keys) in web browsing?

Tags: html, accessibility

Are there any common keyboard navigation practices, used to improve when browsing a web site?

I'm thinking of the accesskey HTML attribute, which lets you define default fields for a specific command, like alt+1 for the link leading to the start page, or similar.

Is there a kind of standard somewhere?

Comment: Also, I've found major corporations like Google, Facebook, Twitter and Microsoft doesn't use accesskey on their websites. I wonder why.

Comment: There are known to be a number of shortcomings with access keys. What should a browser on a mobile phone do? What happens if a key combination conflicts with a browser built-in action? How does a user find out what key combinations are available to them? For major corporations they are probably more trouble than they are worth. HTML5 attempts to address some of the shortcomings by allowing authors to specify a list of candidate keys to use, so the browsers can allocate an unused combination for each action. Whether that will be sufficient to increase their use remains to be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is only UK Government accesskeys standard
http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo-blog/index.php/uk-gov-access-keys/

guess there is no w3c standard
http://www.contraxonline.com/w3c.shtml

Comment: Cheers to this one, very useful!

Answer (score 4):

I’m a screen reader user and rarely use access keys even if they are provided. Do to the fact that each site appears to use their own standard it is usually not worth the trouble to learn them. The only time I make a point to learn the keys is if it’s a site I will use a lot. An example of this is the Safari books site since knowing the keys allows me to navigate through books quicker. I would say that not having access keys on your site is ok. I would recommend putting access keys on your site if you think users will spend enough time on the site to become proficient with doing most things with the keyboard. An example of this may be an order entry system that people spend most of their time in for their job.

Comment: Great addition, Jared. Really interesting!